# MongoDB Replica Set SECONDARY Stuck in `ROLLBACK` State

Tags: mongodb, rollback

During a recent automated update of our mongodb `PRIMARY`, when the `PRIMARY` stepped down it permanently went into a `ROLLBACK` state.

After several hours in the `ROLLBACK` state, there was still no rollback `.bson` file in the `rollback` directory in the mongodb database directory.  That, and also this line in our log file: `[rsSync] replSet syncThread: 13410 replSet too much data to roll back`, seems to indicate that the `ROLLBACK` process failed.

I would like some help analyzing what exactly went wrong.

- It appears two different rollbacks occurred in our logs. Is that the case or was it one that took 3 hours?
- If the first rollback (at 19:00 hours) was successful, why didnt anything appears in ou `rollback` directory?
- Any guess as to the cause of all those warnings? Could that be related to the rollback failure?
- Did we lose 18 seconds of data due to the first `ROLLBACK`?
- Is there a generic solution to the "stuck in `ROLLBACK` state" problem? We ended up having to hose our entire DB and re-sync from primary.

The relevant log lines are:

```
# Primary coming back after restart...
Tue May 15 19:01:01 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=3684 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=magnesium
Tue May 15 19:01:01 [initandlisten] db version v2.0.5, pdfile version 4.5
# ... init stuff
Tue May 15 19:01:01 [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/mongodb/journal
Tue May 15 19:01:01 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
# ... More init stuff
Tue May 15 19:01:03 [rsStart] trying to contact rs1arb1.c9w.co:27017
Tue May 15 19:01:03 [rsStart] trying to contact rs1m2.c9w.co:27017
Tue May 15 19:01:03 [rsStart] replSet STARTUP2
Tue May 15 19:01:03 [rsHealthPoll] replSet member rs1arb1.c9w.co:27017 is up
Tue May 15 19:01:03 [rsHealthPoll] replSet member rs1arb1.c9w.co:27017 is now in state ARBITER
Tue May 15 19:01:03 [rsSync] replSet SECONDARY
Tue May 15 19:01:05 [rsHealthPoll] replSet member rs1m2.c9w.co:27017 is up
Tue May 15 19:01:05 [rsHealthPoll] replSet member rs1m2.c9w.co:27017 is now in state PRIMARY
Tue May 15 19:01:09 [rsSync] replSet syncing to: rs1m2.c9w.co:27017
Tue May 15 19:01:09 [rsSync] replSet our last op time written: May 15 19:00:51:6
Tue May 15 19:01:09 [rsSync] replSet rollback 0
Tue May 15 19:01:09 [rsSync] replSet ROLLBACK
Tue May 15 19:01:09 [rsSync] replSet rollback 1
Tue May 15 19:01:09 [rsSync] replSet rollback 2 FindCommonPoint
Tue May 15 19:01:09 [rsSync] replSet info rollback our last optime:   May 15 19:00:51:6
Tue May 15 19:01:09 [rsSync] replSet info rollback their last optime: May 15 19:01:09:19
Tue May 15 19:01:09 [rsSync] replSet info rollback diff in end of log times: -18 seconds
Tue May 15 19:01:10 [rsSync] replSet WARNING ignoring op on rollback no _id TODO : nimbus.system.indexes { ts: Timestamp 1337108400000|17, h: 1628369028235805797, op: "i", ns: "nimbus.system.indexes", o: { unique: true, name: "pascalquery_ns_key_start_ts_keyvals", key: { __ns__: 1, _key: 1, start_ts: 1, _keyval.a: 1, _keyval.b: 1, _keyval.c: 1, _keyval.d: 1, _keyval.e: 1, _keyval.f: 1, _keyval.g: 1, _keyval.h: 1 }, ns: "nimbus.wifi_daily_series", background: true } }
# ...
# Then for several minutes there are similar warnings
# ...
Tue May 15 19:03:52 [rsSync] replSet WARNING ignoring op on rollback no _id TODO : nimbus.system.indexes { ts: Timestamp 1337097600000|204, h: -3526710968279064473, op: "i", ns: "nimbus.system.indexes", o: { unique: true, name: "pascalquery_ns_key_start_ts_keyvals", key: { __ns__: 1, _key: 1, start_ts: 1, _keyval.a: 1, _keyval.b: 1, _keyval.c: 1, _keyval.d: 1, _keyval.e: 1, _keyval.f: 1, _keyval.g: 1, _keyval.h: 1 }, ns: "nimbus.wifi_daily_series", background: true } }
Tue May 15 19:03:54 [rsSync] replSet rollback found matching events at May 15 15:59:13:181
Tue May 15 19:03:54 [rsSync] replSet rollback findcommonpoint scanned : 6472020
Tue May 15 19:03:54 [rsSync] replSet replSet rollback 3 fixup
```

Then later for some reason another rollback occurs...

```
Tue May 15 22:14:24 [rsSync] replSet rollback re-get objects: 13410 replSet too much data to roll back
Tue May 15 22:14:26 [rsSync] replSet syncThread: 13410 replSet too much data to roll back
Tue May 15 22:14:37 [rsSync] replSet syncing to: rs1m2.c9w.co:27017
Tue May 15 22:14:37 [rsSync] replSet syncThread: 13106 nextSafe(): { $err: "capped cursor overrun during query: local.oplog.rs", code: 13338 }
Tue May 15 22:14:48 [rsSync] replSet syncing to: rs1m2.c9w.co:27017
Tue May 15 22:15:30 [rsSync] replSet our last op time written: May 15 19:00:51:6
Tue May 15 22:15:30 [rsSync] replSet rollback 0
Tue May 15 22:15:30 [rsSync] replSet rollback 1
Tue May 15 22:15:30 [rsSync] replSet rollback 2 FindCommonPoint
Tue May 15 22:15:30 [rsSync] replSet info rollback our last optime:   May 15 19:00:51:6
Tue May 15 22:15:30 [rsSync] replSet info rollback their last optime: May 15 22:15:30:9
Tue May 15 22:15:30 [rsSync] replSet info rollback diff in end of log times: -11679 seconds
# More warnings matching the above warnings
Tue May 15 22:17:30 [rsSync] replSet rollback found matching events at May 15 15:59:13:181
Tue May 15 22:17:30 [rsSync] replSet rollback findcommonpoint scanned : 7628640
Tue May 15 22:17:30 [rsSync] replSet replSet rollback 3 fixup
```

The only useful information on rollbacks I've found are these notes which dont address the "stuck in rollback situation".
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Sets+-+Rollbacks
http://www.snailinaturtleneck.com/blog/2011/01/19/how-to-use-replica-set-rollbacks/

Comment: Did you check write-concern? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-write-concern/#modify-default-write-concern

Answer (score 7):

When a MongoDB instance gets into a Rollback state, and the rollback data is greater than 300MB of data, you have to manually intervene.  It will stay in a rollback state until you take action to save/remove/move that data, the (now secondary) should then be resynced to bring it back in line with the primary.  This does not have to be a full resync, but that is the simplest way.

Multiple rollbacks are a symptom rather than the cause of a problem.  Rollback only happens when a secondary that was not in sync (either due to lag or an issue with replication) becomes primary and takes writes.  So, the problems that cause that to happen in the first place are what need to be taken care of - the rollback itself is something you need to deal with as an admin - there are too many potential pitfalls for MongoDB to reconcile the data automatically.

If you want to simulate this again for testing purposes, I have outlined how to do so here:

http://comerford.cc/2012/05/28/simulating-rollback-on-mongodb/

Eventually, this data will be stored in a collection (in the local DB) rather than dumped to disk, which will present opportunities to deal with it more effectively:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4375

At the moment though, once a rollback occurs, as you found, manual intervention is required.

Finally, the manual contains similar information to Kristina's blog now:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-rollbacks

Answer (score 2):

The "solution" we ended up using was completely hosing our database on the machine which was stuck in `ROLLBACK` mode and allowing the newly blanked `SECONDARY` to re-sync from master. This seems like a suboptimal solution because, as near as I could tell, we still had plenty of space on the `oplog` so the machines should have, in theory, been able to re-sync.

Hopefully someone will come up with a better answer for this.

Comment: Thank you for updating us on what you did. If you find any more information about this, do come back and update your answer (or provide another one).